# Why doesn't the function stat() shadow the struct stat constructor in C++?

Tags: g++, shadowing

If I compile the following code using "g++ -Wshadow -c":

```
struct foo
{
   int x;
};
void foo(char* x, struct foo* y);
```

I get the expected:

> warning: ‘void foo(char*, foo*)’ hides constructor for ‘struct foo’
>   [-Wshadow]
> void foo(char* x, struct foo* y);

Why do I not get the same warning whenever I include the header file "sys/stat.h", which defines both "struct stat" and the function stat()? Does gcc know about stat and treat it specially, or is there something in the headers that suppresses the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is unconditionally suppressed in system headers (not just without `-Wsystem-headers`):

```
  if (to_type != old_type
      && warn_shadow
      && MAYBE_CLASS_TYPE_P (TREE_TYPE (to_type))
      && !(DECL_IN_SYSTEM_HEADER (decl)
           && DECL_IN_SYSTEM_HEADER (to_type)))
    warning (OPT_Wshadow, "%q#D hides constructor for %q#D",
             decl, to_type);
```

You can reproduce this for your example if you put it into a header file in a directory specified using `-isystem` (instead of `-I`).